# Deep linking with go router doesn't navigate to correct screen when app is not launched on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to implement deep linking with go_router. Everything is working fine on Android, but on iOS opening the deep link URL opens the app to the correct screen only if the app is open and it is in the background. If the app is closed, the deep link URL only opens the login screen.

Here is my setup

Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>appscheme</string>
        <string>${GOOGLE_REVERSED_CLIENT_ID}</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
```

app.dart

```
MaterialApp.router(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  routerConfig: GoRouter(
    routes: [ 
      GoRoute( 
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage( key: Key('loginPage',),),
      ), 
      GoRoute( 
        path: '/sign-up',
        builder: (context, state) => const SignUpPage( key: Key('signUpPage'), ), 
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

To invoke deeplink
`xcrun simctl openurl booted "appscheme:/sign-up"`

Comment: Try this https://dwirandyh.medium.com/effortless-routing-deeplink-in-flutter-using-go-router-59edd67c52a0

Comment: I have this bookmarked and also followed it line by line. Still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how you can handle deeplink on iOS:

**Swift Code in AppDelegate.swift:**

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  
  private var methodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?
  private var eventChannel: FlutterEventChannel?
  
  private let linkStreamHandler = LinkStreamHandler()
  
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    
    let controller = window.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    
    // Create a MethodChannel for invoking methods from Dart to Swift
    methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "deeplink.flutter.dev/channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    
    // Create an EventChannel to listen for deep link events from Swift to Dart
    eventChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: "deeplink.flutter.dev/events", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

    // Set up a method call handler for incoming method calls from Dart
    methodChannel?.setMethodCallHandler({ (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) in
      guard call.method == "initialLink" else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        return
      }
    })

    // Register Flutter plugins
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
    // Set the stream handler for the EventChannel to handle incoming deep links
    eventChannel?.setStreamHandler(linkStreamHandler)
    
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  
  // Handle deep link events when the app is already open
  override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // Set the stream handler for the EventChannel to handle the deep link
    eventChannel?.setStreamHandler(linkStreamHandler)
    return linkStreamHandler.handleLink(url.absoluteString)
  }
}

// Create a class to handle incoming deep links
class LinkStreamHandler: NSObject, FlutterStreamHandler {
  
  var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?
  
  // Store links in a queue until the sink is ready to process them
  var queuedLinks = [String]()
  
  func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
    self.eventSink = events
    
    // Send any queued links to the sink
    queuedLinks.forEach({ events($0) })
    queuedLinks.removeAll()
    
    return nil
  }
  
  func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
    self.eventSink = nil
    return nil
  }
  
  func handleLink(_ link: String) -> Bool {
    guard let eventSink = eventSink else {
      // Queue the link if the event sink is not ready
      queuedLinks.append(link)
      return false
    }
    // Send the link to the event sink
    eventSink(link)
    return true
  }
}
```

**Explanation for AppDelegate.swift:**

- In `AppDelegate.swift`, we set up deep link handling for a Flutter app running on iOS.
- We create a `MethodChannel` named "deeplink.flutter.dev/channel" to allow Dart to invoke methods in Swift.
- An `EventChannel` named "deeplink.flutter.dev/events" is created to listen for deep link events from Swift to Dart.
- We set a method call handler to handle method calls from Dart, specifically the "initialLink" method.
- Flutter plugins are registered with `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)`.
- The `LinkStreamHandler` class handles incoming deep links and sends them to the Flutter app.

Now, let's explain the Dart code in `main.dart`:

**Dart Code in main.dart:**

```dart
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Event Channel creation
  const stream = EventChannel('deeplink.flutter.dev/events');

  // Method channel creation
  const platform = MethodChannel('deeplink.flutter.dev/channel');

  Future<String?> startUri() async {
    try {
      return platform.invokeMethod('initialLink');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return "Failed to Invoke: '${e.message}'.";
    }
  }

  onRedirected(String? uri) {
    debugPrint("uri: $uri");
    if (uri == "deeplink://login") {
      GoRouter.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).push('/login');
    } else if (uri == "deeplink://sign-up") {
      GoRouter.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).push('/sign-up');
    }
  }

  stream.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((d) {
    // Checking application start by deep link
    startUri().then(onRedirected);
    // Checking broadcast stream if a deep link was clicked in an opened application
    stream.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((d) => onRedirected(d));
  });

  runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router));
}

// Define your GoRouter routes and pages
final router = GoRouter(
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  initialLocation: "/login",
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/login',
      builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(
        key: Key('loginPage'),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/sign-up',
      builder: (context, state) => const SignUpPage(
        key: Key('signUpPage'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);

// Define your Flutter pages
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Login")),
      body: const Center(child: Text("Login Page")),
    );
  }
}

class SignUpPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Sign Up")),
      body: const Center(child: Text("Sign Up Page")),
    );
  }
}
```

**Explanation for main.dart:**

- In `main.dart`, we set up deep link handling

for a Flutter app.

- We create an `EventChannel` named "deeplink.flutter.dev/events" to listen for deep link events from Swift to Dart.
- A `MethodChannel` named "deeplink.flutter.dev/channel" is created to invoke methods in Swift.
- `startUri` is a function that attempts to invoke the "initialLink" method from Swift and handles exceptions.
- `onRedirected` is a function that processes deep link URIs, pushing corresponding routes using the GoRouter package.
- We listen to the broadcast stream to check for deep links both when the app starts and while it's running.
- The `router` object defines routes and pages for the GoRouter package.

These code segments together enable seamless handling of deep links between Flutter and native iOS code, allowing control over deep link transitions within the Flutter app on iOS using Swift. While the provided Swift code works well, the uni_links package offers a more convenient and feature-rich solution for deep link handling in Flutter applications. You can find more information about the uni_links package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links).

For more details, you can refer to the article [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283).

Comment: I don't think this implementation goes with go_router package. go_router handles deeplink by default. The only issue I'm having is with relaunched iOS state

Comment: I used the go router even though it is not working by default you can manually control the route. This way you have control of both URLs coming from background or closed state

Comment: But I think go_router should handle this without me going this route. If it doesn't work then I'll definitely try this approach.

Comment: Good luck... but if the default way didn't work I recommend using uni_links it makes it easier. you don't have to manually configure the Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the URL you're trying to pass. Instead of passing the path after the scheme, add a host.

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted "appscheme://somehost.com/sign-up"
```

[Here's](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100624) a link to the GitHub issue which demonstrates the same behaviour.